# Spring Cloud Stream is creating exchange on Consumer service startup

Tags: spring, microservices, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

I have two microservices `Student` and `Teacher`

in `Student` microservice I am creating a `MessageSink` for exchange `XYZ`

```
@Input("XYZ")
SubscribableChannel xyz();
```

and in `Teacher` microservice I am configuring exchange `XYZ` as a `fanout`

**application.properties**

```
 spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.XYZ.producer.exchangeType=fanout
 spring.cloud.stream.bindings.XYZ.contentType=application/json
```

But problem I am facing here is `Student` service is starting before `Teacher` service and it is creating `XYZ exchange` with type `Topic` and then `Teacher` service starting is giving me following error:

```
amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin - Failed to declare exchange: Exchange [name=XYZ, type=fanout, durable=true, autoDelete=false, internal=false, arguments={}], continuing... com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'type' for exchange 'XYZ' in vhost '/': received 'fanout' but current is 'topic', class-id=40, method-id=10)
```

so is there any configuration to change the `exchangeType` or delete existing `exchange` and create new `exchange` or set `exchangeType` in `@Input` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider to disable exchange creation there via configuration properties:

```
declareExchange

    Whether to declare the exchange for the destination.

    Default: true.
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.M3/reference/htmlsingle/#_rabbitmq_consumer_properties

Comment: You can also set the `exchangeType` on the consumer side. If you are using customized exchange types, it must be the same on both sides. Find `exchangeType` [on this page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Ditmars.SR1/reference/htmlsingle/index.html) and you can see it's available for both producers and consumers.